# How to work with cordova file plugin in ionic 2

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic2

I am working on ionic 2.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#persistent

I have installed file plugin using this command `ionic plugin add cordova-file-plugin` But i don't know how to get work with it.

any demo for working with ionic 2, where should i start from.

My requirement is saving the username and password to a file and even they close the app they should be going to the home page since the correct username and password is stored in the file.

If the user enters the wrong username and password and it should also store in the file but they should be seeing only the login page.

here is my code

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {File} from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    private userName: any;
    private password: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.userName = "Admin";
    this.password = "Admin123";

  }

    createFile(dirEntry, fileName, isAppend) {
        // Creates a new file or returns the file if it already exists.
        dirEntry.getFile(fileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {

            writeFile(fileEntry, null, isAppend);

        }, onErrorCreateFile);

    }
}
```

> i am getting error on `writeFile` and `onErrorCreateFile` what should i do to get ride of those error in typescript.
>
> How to store my username and password to my file how can i check it whether i have stored or not like that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever store that in a file, use ionic storage, works incredibly well!

https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/